# what will happen if i leave my smartphone(samsung gt8150) with an already ruined battery a whole day plugged into the computer?

Tags: battery, tethering

I use my smartphone for tethering and i have a ruined battery which will keep the device on for not more than 1 minute but can be plugged in to the computer or charger.Is it ok to leave the device for a  whole night or a whole day for tethering? Will it damage the smartphone?
I edit to specify that im using usb wifi tethering

Answer (score 0):

Well, its okay to leave the device plugged over to the charger with a ruined battery. Let me tell you a little secrete I am doing the same thing thing from last month, What I need was a router so, I got the idea the same way like you are talking about I plugged my s2 with the charger with tethering switched on and viola I no need of spending few extra bucks for router. I use it to tether the internet over my notebook and s5. Still no sign of any unusual problem, I usually switch the charger off when I am at my workplace. So, I would say instead of keeping it switch on continuously switch it off when not in use you will never encounter any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a **yes** based on the conditions of the battery.

If the battery is not more then  1 year old(frequently charging or extreme usage of the device for the most of the time)

If the battery has any dent's etc.

If the battery is showing early signs of disfiguring.(Battery starts to swell due to overcharging which leads to overheating and thereby it will not fit in your device leaving your device useless for any purpose you desire which require using the battery i.e. dead phone without battery)

If the your battery satisfies anyone condition from the above then you have to replace the battery with a new one.

Comment: thanks very much for reply, i understand but will using long time tethering with broken battery ruin <the phone>?

Comment: its surely deteriorated becouse is bigger than usual and doesnt work ok at all. i have another i wanted to use it only for downloads too big for the smartphone

Comment: yes Replace now don't wait further for any untoward incident may happen